# If I have both simple and compound index on a field, which one gets used in queries containing that field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

I have a field "productLowerCase" in my mongo documents. I created 2 indices

```
1. simple
   {"productLowerCase" : 1}
2. compound
   {"productLowerCase" : 1, "timestamp.milliseconds" : -1}
```

So If I run a query which has only productLowerCase, say:

```
db.coll.find({"productLowerCase" : {$regex : /^cap/}})
```

Which index will get used?

Answer (score 0):

In this case mongo will use `{"productLowerCase" : 1}` this index, but you can remove this index, because if you have compound index you can search with first field without performance loss.

Beside this you can use `explain()` to explain your query.